# INotifyPropertyChanged not connecting inside WndProc Message

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, wndproc

I am currently working on a Windows desktop application in WPF. It is build around the MVVM pattern, therefore the view is binded to the viewmodel via INotifyPropertyChanged with the help of the Telerik library. The application as a whole works well but one module requires messages from a hardware instrument. This instrument only sends information via WndMessage, meaning we implement the WndProc method.

The WndProc method works as expected except for the fact that any binding call is not received by the view. We tested the bindings outside the WndProc and they work well. Sadly, we tried to trigger the notification via invoke and manual refreshing but to no avail.

Is there a way for the notify message to reach the view during a WndProc? I provided snippet of the code but the code itself is really simple.

*Databinding*

```
public List<PlotCoordinate> PointsList
{
    get
    {
        return _pointsList;
    }
}
```

*WndProc message reception*

```
private static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
{
    MainWindowViewModel viewModel = _dataContext;
    InstrumentViewModel instrument = viewModel.InstrumentViewModelReference as InstrumentViewModel;
    instrument?.ProcessMessage(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam, ref handled);

    return IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

*Data manipulation inside the WndProc*

```
public void DrawGraphFromInstrumentData()
{
    // Clear previous data and prepare new series
    _pointsList = new List<PlotCoordinate>();

    // ... fill the list with new data

    OnPropertyChanged("PointsList");
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

After some fooling around I think I managed to identify the problem. The problem is not the `_dataContext` but at this line :

```
InstrumentViewModel instrument = viewModel.InstrumentViewModelReference as InstrumentViewModel;
```

Using the `_dataContext` directly activates the `PropertyChanged` but using the `instrument` does not. I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: "any binding call is not received by the view" -- What's a binding call? Why do you call a property a "databinding"?

Comment: I did a quick test and `PropertyChanged` works fine when raised inside a static `WndProc` method. Your guess about the cause was wrong. So what you're going to need to do is figure out what's happening here, or provide a minimal code example sufficient to reproduce what you're seeing so we can figure it out.

Comment: @EdPlunkett Thanks alot for the feedback. By binding call I mean PropertyChanged call.  I will try to make a small program to reproduce the behaviour and I'll edit back the question.

Comment: Make sure you don't have two copies of the viewmodel floating around. Sometimes people create one in the XAML and one in the constructor. That static `_dataContext` field deserves close scrutiny IMO.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I think you are right about the `_dataContext`. I made a light application and `PropertyChanged` was working fine inside a static `WndProc`.  I will look more closely at your recommandation and try to find the problem.  Strangely tho, the `_dataContext` is always up-to-date with the application's properties.

Comment: Hmm. If it’s definitely up to date, I might’ve guessed wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `ObservableCollection<PlotCoordinate>` instead of just your `List<PlotCoordinate>`. Be sure to be on the UI thread when adding to this list, and your View should recognize when new items are added rather than just when the List itself is changed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I already tried with an ObservableCollection and the result is the same. Also, I verified and the modification of the list occurs on the UI thread.

Comment: Using an ObservableCollection is pointless here, because a new collection instance is created and populated before firing the PropertyChanged event. The collection isn't modified later. This post doesn't answer the question.